# How to change Custom field date picker to appear as Month-Year picker

Tags: jira, custom-fields, jira-plugin

How to change default datepicker template to appear as Month-Year view only .

below is the template file for detault date picker custom field:

```
##disable_html_escaping() TODO REENABLE
$!{auiparams.put("controlHeaderClass", "aui-field-datepicker")}
#customControlHeader ($action $customField.id $customField.name $fieldLayoutItem.required     $displayParameters $auiparams)
## Show the use checkbox field to use the current date/time when configuring the field in the   admin section.
#if ($displayParameters.defaultScreen)
<input class="text medium-field datepicker-input" id="$customField.id" name="$customField.id"   type="text" value="$!value" />
<a href="#" id="${customField.id}-trigger" title="$i18n.getText('date.picker.select.date')">
    <span class="aui-icon icon-date">$i18n.getText('date.picker.select.date')</span>
</a>
#datePopup(${customField.id} "${customField.id}-trigger" $dateTimeFormat $dateFormat $timeFormat    $dateTimePicker $currentMillis $currentCalendar)
<div class="checkbox field-default">
    #if($dateTimePicker)
        #set ($labelText = $i18n.getText('date.picker.config.default.datetime'))
    #else
        #set ($labelText = $i18n.getText('date.picker.config.default.date'))
    #end
    <input#if ($customField.customFieldType.isUseNow($config)) checked="checked"#end  class="checkbox" id="useCurrentDate" name="useCurrentDate" type="checkbox" value="true" />
    <label for="useCurrentDate">${labelText}</label>
</div>
#else
<input class="text medium-field datepicker-input" id="$customField.id" name="$customField.id"     type="text" value="$!value" />
<a href="#" id="${customField.id}-trigger" title="$i18n.getText('date.picker.select.date')">
    <span class="aui-icon icon-date">$i18n.getText('date.picker.select.date')</span>
</a>
#datePopup(${customField.id} "${customField.id}-trigger" $dateTimeFormat $dateFormat $timeFormat       $dateTimePicker $currentMillis $currentCalendar)
#end
#customControlFooter ($action $customField.id $fieldLayoutItem.fieldDescription    $displayParameters $auiparams)
$!{auiparams.clear()}
```

I need to create cascade month-calendar picker custom field which can show only Month-Year instead of date.

EXAMPLE:
Issue Edit screen:

```
                <CALENDAR CONTROL>     <CALENDAR CONTROL>       <CALENDAR CONTROL>
field1          <text>
field2          <text>
field3          <text>
```

when we select calander value then appears as below:

```
                APR-2013     APR-2014       APR-2015
```

so, if some how we could update existing date picker cusotm field to show as "month-year" view then i could create a "AbstractCustomFieldType" custom field and use it.

NOTE: I need this field to save along with the other field in issue edit screen.

Thank You

Comment: can you add a mock-up of the required result?

Comment: Hi Kuf, updated question with detail. Thanks.

Comment: @Kuf   Hi, i am still looking around this .. if any update then please let me know.